# aws iot set-logging-options fails on unicode character

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I'm trying to turn logging on my AWS IOT account and I get the following error when setting logging options via the command line.

Here is the command:
`aws iot set-logging-options --logging-options-payload roleArn=”arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/iot-logging-role”,logLevel=”INFO”`

Here is the error:
`'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201d' in position 83: ordinal not in range(128)`

I know this is related to python unicode/ascii conversion, but I'm not sure if this is a bug in aws or something I can configure myself.

Comment: Note: os = ubuntu 12.04 python version = 2.7.3

Comment: Also aws-cli version 1.9.0

Answer (score 1):

This command worked once i removed the quotes.

aws iot set-logging-options --logging-options-payload roleArn=arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/iot-logging-role,logLevel=INFO

Comment: Note the AWS IOT setting up cloud watch tutorial needs to be updated to remove the quotes http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/cloud-watch-logs.html